# index.html is not getting deployed in Angular2

Tags: c#, angular, iis, asp.net-core

I have created an ASP.Net Core project with Angular2 as front end.

I have placed the index.html file in the main folder of the UI Project and when I compile and publish the project it is not getting deployed to publish folder. The below is the code I have used for it in `Startup.cs`

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => {
            await next();

            if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 &&
                !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value) &&
                !context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api"))
            {
                context.Request.Path = "/index.html";

                await next();
            }
        });
```

When I try to access the file from IIS directly, it says it cannot be found.

The App URL is `http://localhost:81/`

The content of bs-config.json is as follows

```
{
"server": {
"baseDir": "./dist",
"routes": {
   "/node_modules": "node_modules"
  }
 }
}
```

But there is no ./dist folder in the project.

This is the content of the index.html file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Node Junction</title>
    <base href="http://localhost:81">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/styles.css">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>


    <script src="src/systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('main.js').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
    </script>
</head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is there any clue for this?

Comment: is it in the `wwwroot` folder?

Comment: No. Its not in the wwwroot folder

Comment: I am getting yellow mark for lite-server(2.3.0) in npm section of Dependencies. Is that the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Put index.html in the wwwroot folder. That’s the folder from which static files should be served.